# Weather API error {"cod":"400","message":"{vlat} is not a float"}

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get the api coordinates for my local weather app project and this is my link from open weather map

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat='+lat+'&lon='+long+'&appid=7cc72055cf03c02e9bf988f2a7b7b7e2
```

I get this error message every time I try to open the link.

> {"cod":"400","message":"{vlat} is not a float"}

Also it prevents my console from pulling my location. Here is a link to my code.

https://codepen.io/andreacarr/pen/eEMeMr?editors=1111

Please help and let me know what seems to be the error

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` call is asynchronous, hence you're trying to use `lat` and `long` both before they are defined and out of scope.

To fix this you need to put the `$.getJSON` call within the callback of the geolocation logic, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var long;
  var lat;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;
      $("#data").html("latitude: " + lat + "<br>longitude: " + long);

      var api = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + long + '&appid=7cc72055cf03c02e9bf988f2a7b7b7e2';
      $.getJSON(api, function(data) {
        console.log(data.coord.lon);
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  background: url(http://s1.picswalls.com/wallpapers/2016/06/06/beach-desktop-background_090607928_305.jpg)center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  font-family: lobster;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>Local Weather</header>
<p id="data"></p>
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dh4s5bj1/)

Note this example has to be created in a jsFiddle as geolocation doesn't work in a Stack Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when the `latitude` or `longitude` value is not exist

Answer (score 0):

This is because the coordinates is out of range.

Latitudes range from -90 to 90.

Longitudes range from -180 to 180.

http://www.geomidpoint.com/latlon.html

Comment: Upvoting this answer because this message will occur when a longitude >90 or <-90 is erroneously placed in the latitude parameter.